# write Data to a file in Formta Form

Tags: shell, unix

I have Data which is in this below format in **FILE 1**

```
NAME :  Ram 
AGE :  12
NAME :  Rahul
AGE:  13
NAME:   Raj
AGE:   14
```

**My Desired Output => In this Below Format I needed**

I want to Write Data to the **FILE 2** in this below Format like

```
NAME| AGE
Ram|12
Rahul|13
Raj|14
```

**My code :**

```
head -2 file1.txt | nl | tr '\n' '|' >> file2.txt
```

**But my Above Code Prints Only in first Two line in File2.txt**

```
1 NAME : Ram | 2 AGE : 12|
```

it has to loop until the end and write to file 2

Comment: well, by using `head`, you limit your output to 2 lines., though i don't recognize the `-2` option. afaik to select 2 lines you use `-n 2`. personally I'd have used `sed`

Comment: @FalcoGer => How do I Achieve my Desired Output => Could you Suggest me the Change I need to make to make it Work

Comment: Strip `Name: `, and replace `\nAge: ` with | . you might have to use tr to temporarily replace `\n` with another character since sed only handles whole lines.

Comment: so now you want the output aligned with by |? And you have variable amounts pf spaces in your input file?

Comment: Why are you using `head`?

Comment: Please => stop => putting random => arrows in your => comments => => => =>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments in code. The script:

```
# input test file as provided by OP
cat <<EOF >file
NAME :  Ram 
AGE :  12
NAME :  Rahul
AGE:  13
NAME:   Raj
AGE:   14
EOF

# My first solution - a simple bash while read loop
echo "NAME|AGE"
while IFS=': ' read -r _ name && IFS=': ' read -r _ age; do
    echo "$name|$age"
done <file

# Second solution - some parsing + xargs
# first remove spaces, then substitue `:` for a space
# then run printf, don't print any NAME and AGE %.0s and print the names and ages %s
echo "NAME|AGE"
<file tr -d ' ' | tr ':' ' ' | xargs printf "%.0s%s|%.0s%s\n"

# Third solution - sed!
# first remove spaces and remove everything before :
# then read two lines, substitue newline for a | and print
echo "NAME|AGE"
<file sed 's/ //g; s/.*://' | sed 'N;s/\n/|/'
```

will output:

```
NAME|AGE
Ram|12
Rahul|13
Raj|14
NAME|AGE
Ram|12
Rahul|13
Raj|14
NAME|AGE
Ram|12
Rahul|13
Raj|14
```

Tested at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/64dhOa)

Comment: Could you be able to take NAME and AGE only once as header on the Top first line

Comment: @volmokirti how about you read the actual code instead of copy pasting and then wondering why it doesn't work. it clearly states that those are three possible solutions, thus the output will be printed trice.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will do what you want

```
#!/bin/bash
input="./file1.txt"
evenLine=0

# this will overwrite file2.txt
echo "Name|Age" > file2.txt

# loop over all lines
while IFS= read -r line
do
  if [ 0 -eq $evenLine ]
  then
    # -n to not append newline, remove string "Name: "
    echo -n "$line" | sed -e "s/Name: *//g" >> file2.txt
    evenLine=1
  else
    # replace "Age: " with " | "
    echo "$line" | sed -e "s/Age: */ | /g" >> file2.txt
    evenLine=0
  fi
done < "$input"
```

Comment: @FalcoGer ...Have you look at the Desired Output... your code does not print what is expected ... header should be printed only once

Comment: @volmokirti it does. the header is written to the file above the loop start.